# Cypress file uploading error with cypress-file-upload

Tags: vuejs2, cypress

In my vue/cli 4 / Bootstrap 4.3 app I use vue-upload-component component for files uploading
and it works ok. I want to add cypress for testing file uploading and I
added https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload/tree/v3.5.3 into my project, but failed 
with this testing.
I have in vue file:

```html
    <file-upload
            ref="upload"
            v-model="imageFiles"
            post-action="/post.method"
            put-action="/put.method"
            @input-file="inputFile"
            @input-filter="inputFilter"
            :multiple="false"
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm m-2 file-input-class"
            data-cy="file-input"
    >
        <i :class="'action_link '+getHeaderIcon('upload')"></i>Upload image
    </file-upload>

    ...
   const VueUploadComponent = require('vue-upload-component')
   Vue.component('file-upload', VueUploadComponent)
```

and in my browser it is rendered into :

```html
<span class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm m-2 file-input-class file-uploads file-uploads-html5" data-cy="file-input">
    <i class="action_link fa fa-upload"></i>
    Upload image  
    <label for="file"></label> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</span>
```

I cypress test file I do :

```js
        import 'cypress-file-upload'
        describe('Admin category fileupload functionality', () => {
            ...
            const fileName = '/sample_images/sample.png';

            cy.contains('Image Preview/Upload')

            cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
                //  cy.find('#file')
                //     .should('have.value', 'Invalid Text')

                console.log('++Inside Tests cy::')
                console.log(cy)

                cy.get('#file').upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'image/png' });
            });
```

But in the console I got error:

> THEN  function(){}
>   TypeError: cy.get(...).upload is not a function

I see next ouput of cy var :

[image]

Also in testing code above to uncomment 2 lines :

```
cy.find('#file')
    .should('have.value', 'Invalid Text')
```

I do not have should errors, as I expected, asnd I do not understand why ?

How to make file uploading testing?

```
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"cypress-file-upload": "^4.0.6",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-upload-component": "^2.8.20",
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have anybody uploaded files in cypress? Please, share your expierence...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're showing `"^4.0.6"` as your `cypress-file-upload` version. There is a difference between the [latest version](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload) and [version 3.5.3](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload/tree/v3.5.3).

The exposed command has changed from `upload()` to `attachFile()` since version 4.0.0

[image]

There is also a note in the latest version saying it's unstable at the moment. Maybe you should revert back to 3.5.3 and keep your code as is.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like you are right version 3.5.3 working. I am making tests now. Also could you please where did you find ref to attachFile ? upload( works with 3.5.3 ok...

Comment: here https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload#usage and
here https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload#api